# Find most purchased product

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is a simplified version of my problem.
Suppose I have a **products** table

```
products
-------------
id      name        
1       chocolate       
2       pepsi       
3       apple       
4       chips
```

and **orders** table

```
orders
-------------------------------------------
id      product_id      quantity    user_id
1           1           2               1
2           1           2               2
3           1           2               3
4           1           2               4
5           2           5               5
6           2           5               6
7           3           20              7
```

For every purchase by user we would insert a row in orders table along with the product's ID and how many units he ordered

I want to get the list of products in descending order of their purchase ie. starting from most purchased to the least one. But the problem is ranking depends not only on how many times it was purchased by users (row count) but also on *how many units where purchased* in that single order.

here is what I have tried

```
SELECT products.name 
FROM orders left join products
ON ( orders.product_id = products.id )
GROUP by orders.product_id
ORDER by count(orders.product_id)  desc;
```

which is clearly wrong as it gives

```
chocolate
pepsi
apple
```

rather than

```
apple
pepsi
chocolate
```

Regards

Comment: Shouldnt you order by product_id but count with quantity?

Comment: what will happen if you remove `desc` from `ORDER BY` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `ORDER BY` the `SUM` of quantity:

```
SELECT products.name, SUM(orders.quantity) AS sum_quantity
FROM orders LEFT JOIN products ON orders.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY orders.product_id
ORDER BY sum_quantity DESC;
```

> **demo (with comparison of `SUM` and `COUNT`):** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1ec57/2/0

You are using `COUNT` at the moment. So you only get the number of `orders` but not the quantity of ordered `products`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `SUM`, e.g.:

```
SELECT name
FROM products
WHERE id IN (
 SELECT product_id
 FROM orders
 GROUP BY producy_id
 ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC
);
```